# Show Image While Designing

Tags: java, swing

I created a component to display Image in `jPanel`.But its not showing the image during design time.how to show Image on design time?

```
public class JImagePanel extends JPanel {
private BufferedImage _img=null;

public JImagePanel() {
  super();
}

public void setImage(URL img) {
   try{
    this._img = ImageIO.read(img);
    validate();
    repaint();
   }catch(Exception err){

   }

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  if(this._img!=null)
  g.drawImage(_img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display [Icon/ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) only, then better would be look for [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) as painting background by using `paintComponent(Graphics g)`